# PHP getimagesize and $_FILES type not working

Tags: php, html, file, error-handling

I just fall into this problem today. So this is an image upload script in PHP and the problem is that it is successfully uploading some images but not every image.

**For some images, it is not even detecting the type and image size.**

Here:

```
if (isset($_FILES["image"]["name"])) {
    $fileName = $_FILES["image"]["name"];
    if(!empty($fileName)){
       $imageType=$_FILES['image']['type'];
       $imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($fileName, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
       $imagetemp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];

       $image_size= getimagesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
       $imageWidth=$image_size[0];$imageHeight=$image_size[1];

       if(strcmp(substr($imageType, 0, 5), 'image')!=0){ // 
          header('Location: go back if not an image');
          die();
       }else if(($imageWidth < 1280) && ($imageHeight < 720)){
        header('Location: ../createEvent.php?load=1&error=imageresolution');
        die();
       }
}}
```

**For valid images, it returns no width and height.**

Comment: make sure you are uploading images with extension.

Comment: Don't use `$_FILES['image']['type']` to check if the file is an image. It is information sent by the browser and it contain anything. Use [`finfo_file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-file.php).

Comment: Check,image size it's not more than 1024 kb for your local server.

Comment: What do you mean